# Error: No neutral-language version resource found in the file

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, tfs-2015

I am using TFS 2015 CI to publish my application but during Nuget Restore. I am getting error.

```
"Error: No neutral-language version resource found in the file"
```

I have added neutral-language to my project but its not working at all.

Have you guys ever faced this error?

Answer (score 0):

Which Nuget Version do you use? Seems the Nuget version 4.x have issues.

> The message you are seeing is related to some code in the nuget task
>   where we are trying to detect the nuget version and its associated
>   'quirks'. Newer versions of nuget (e.g. 4.x) have fewer issues.
>
> ***Source link*** : [NuGet Restore Intermittently Fails #4759](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/4759)

As a workaround, you can fall back to NuGet 3.5., specify "3.5.0" as the version of NuGet in `Path to NuGet.exe` to use.

Comment: @Sagar Any update? Is the workaround working for you?

Comment: Andy, I'm getting this same error, but in the `NuGet tool installer` task when I'm specifying 5.10.0. I tried backing it off to 3.5.0, as you suggested here, but I didn't get much further with that (at least ADS 2020 made it to "Downloading" in the log w/3.5.0—there weren't any log entries at all w/5.10.0). This is my first rodeo with YAML with a new pipeline; with Classic the `NuGet tool installer` task succeeds w/5.10.0 but the `NuGet restore` task fails as above with the same message, with both v3.5.0 and 5.10.0. This is pretty serious. I can't build, I can't deploy. Server down.

Comment: I restarted the server and it now works under YAML w/4.0.0, but it still fails w/3.5.0 and 5.10.0. It also works under Classic w/3.5.0, 4.0.0 and 5.10.0. So at least there's a workaround or two. (FYI the failures now are all at the `NuGet restore` step, not the `NuGet tool installer` step. The restart must have flushed that out.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I met the same issue recently, I fix this issue by replacement of nuget.exe on the agent server directly.

My self-hosted agent server was run as a wnidows service, I use "NuGet tool installer" as well, I found the nuget.exe downloaded by "NuGet tool installer" would got error "access denied" when I run it in command line. so I download nuget.exe manually, then replace the agent_folder/tools/nuget/x64/nuget.exe with the one manually downloaded, it works.