# Azure DevOps, pipeline nuget restore failed No neutral-language version resource found in the file

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

I can't solve an error from Nuget Restore in pipeline of Azure DevOps.

```
Starting: NuGet restore
==============================================================================
Task         : NuGet
Description  : Restore, pack, or push NuGet packages, or run a NuGet command. Supports NuGet.org and 
authenticated feeds like Azure Artifacts and MyGet. Uses NuGet.exe and works with .NET Framework apps. For .NET Core and .NET Standard apps, use the .NET Core task.
Version      : 2.161.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget
==============================================================================
##[error]No neutral-language version resource found in the file
Finishing: NuGet restore
```

this is my NUGET Restore step in YAML:

```
steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 3.5.0'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 3.5.0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: 'Projects/Wpf Helper.sln'
    vstsFeed: '9d280068-ebce-4e32-9320-8e07068cc0e0'
```

I've read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47346214/error-no-neutral-language-version-resource-found-in-the-file) and changed nuget version from 3.5.0 to 5.3.1, none of these version helps, same error : No neutral-language version resource found in the file.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's a bug in NuGet, but unless we know what resource it's looking for, it's going to be very difficult to fix. Can you try passing the `-verbose` argument to nuget.exe? That might give a stack trace which will help immensely.

Comment: @zivkan Sorry I don't see the 'argument' field in Nuget Restore Task.

Comment: [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops) says there's a `verbosityRestore` parameter you can use.